# Conditionals based on number of list items?

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make a conditional based on the number of items in a list for a text-based game. For example, in this game, the player needs to collect 6 items before entering the room with the villain in it. If they do not have all 6 items, a message will come up saying they've lost, and the game will end.

I know that to count items in a list, I should be using len(list), but I'm not sure how to incorporate that into a conditional (if it's possible). Here's what I've tried:

```
def main():
    current_room = 'Main Hall'
    inventory = []

    while True:
        print('You are in the', current_room + '.')
        print('Inventory:', inventory)
        print('----------')
        print('What would you like to do?')
        user_input = input('> ')
        print()        
        if current_room == 'Workshop':
            if len(inventory) == 6:
            print('You defeated the abominable snowman and helped save 
            Christmas!')
            print('Thanks for playing!')
            break
        else:
            print('You did not collect all of the items and the abominable snowman has destroyed the 
            workshop!')
            print('Better luck next year, thanks for playing!')
            break
        directions = rooms[current_room].keys()
        if user_input not in directions:
            print('You can\'t go that way!')
            print()
            continue
        current_room = rooms[current_room][user_input]
        room_item = rooms[current_room]["item"]
        print('You see the', room_item + '.')
```

What is supposed to happen in this room is that the game will end. Currently, the game continues and doesn't print any of this. Instead I get "You are in the workshop. What would you like to do?"

I haven't seen much on how to do this, so forgive me if my code is completely wonky. I honestly have no idea what I'm doing, so I'm trying different things in hopes that I'm right. Also if I missed anything (like if I should be showing more of my code, I left out the dictionary I'm using and the instructions function, as well as the code to move from room to room as I felt these were all irrelevant to my question) please let me know :)
Thanks!

EDIT:
I added the rest of my code excluding the dictionary I'm using, maybe the problem lies within what comes after the conditionals?

Comment: Nothing ever happens to make `current_room == 'Workshop'`.

Comment: Your `if current_room ...` is **after** the infinite while-loop, therefore it is never reached. The check for the number of list items is ok.

Comment: oh! I made a mistake writing out my code in the post, I fixed it now. Originally the if statement WAS in the while loop. Just didn't indent properly here

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is outside the while loop. Here is the correct code:

```
def main():
current_room = 'Main Hall'
inventory = []

while True:
    print('You are in the', current_room + '.')
    print('Inventory:', inventory)
    print('----------')
    print('What would you like to do?')
    user_input = input('> ')
    print()        
    if current_room == 'Workshop':
        if len(inventory) == 6:
            print('You defeated the abominable snowman and helped save Christmas!')
            print('Thanks for playing!')
            break
        else:
            print('You did not collect all of the items and the abominable snowman has destroyed the workshop!')
            print('Better luck next year, thanks for playing!')
            break
```

Comment: Please respond if there is still an error or something that you don't want to happen.

Comment: I made a mistake in writing out my code in the post but it's fixed now, my original code actually looks exactly as yours does here hence my confusion!